# How to create a dropdown list on Excel that that a user can click multiple options and it will fill an adjacent cells, for a range of 300 rows?

Tags: excel

I have a single cell A2 that needs to be filled with a string that's one or more items from a given list with 20 items. We have to manually input these values in alphabetic order separated by ";".

Is there a way that we can have a dropdown list on cell A2, that we could pick these values from a checklist, and by clicking on them, they would get inserted?

If so, how can I have this and use it for several rows (A2-A366) where each row is a different data entry for another day but with the same logic?

Note: this has been done here https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3922-excel-drop-down-list-with-checkboxes.html however it was only for one rows. I needed something that could be replicated for 300 rows without having to go through the link instructions 300x.

Thanks!